# i can't insert a record to my table by using mysqli_query()

Tags: php, mysql

i am new on PHP programming .so that i don't understand why my code don't work(and don't show any error)
i want to insert new record to my table sinhvien
here is my code:

```
<?php
$con=new mysqli("localhost","root");
$con->select_db('learn_mysql');
$query="INSERT INTO sinhvien (ho,ten,tuoi) VALUES ('le','van cuong',26)";
$con->query($query);
$con->close();
?>
```

it is run ok but no record insert to my table.

Comment: you need to check this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php

Comment: try checking [`$con->connect_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php) -> `if($con->connect_error) echo $con->connect_error` AND [`$con->error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) -> `$con->query($query) or die($con->error);`

Comment: thats not how you connect. See the answer below.

Comment: You need to specify the password

Comment: @Mihai according to the docs - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php, the password is optional. although not recommended,

Answer (score 1):

You're not connecting correctly, try the following:

```
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "YOURS";
  $dbname = "learn_mysql";

  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());  exit(); }

  $sql = "INSERT INTO `sinhvien`(`ho`, `ten`, `tuoi`) VALUES ('le','van coung','26')";
  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {    } else {echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;}

  $conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to go through some php mysqli basic tutorials. Also try using `mysqli in a object oriented way with mysqli Prepared statements`.

Here are below of my two examples

0) CONNECT TO DATABASE WITH MYSQLI

```
<?php
$localhost='localhost';
    $username='root';
    $password='admin';
    $databaseName='example';

    $con = new mysqli($localhost,$username,$password,$databaseName);

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        die("connection Failed: ".mysqli_connect_errno());
    }
```

1) MYSQLI OBJECT OREINTED WAY

```
//THIS IS ONE OF THE WAYS OF INSERTING DATA IN MYSQL USING MYSQLI
$sql="INSERT INTO sinhvien (ho,ten,tuoi) VALUES ('THIS','WAY ALSO WORKS',26)";
if($con->query($sql) === TRUE){
    echo "INSERTED INTO THE DATA BASE";
}
```

2)MYSQLI OBJECT ORIENTED WITH MYSQLI PREPARED STATEMENTS

```
//THIS IS ONE OF THE WAYS OF INSERTING DATA IN MYSQL USING MYSQLI PREPARED STATEMENT WHICH IS MORE SECURE AGAINST MYSQL INJECTION
$query=$con->stmt_init(); //INITIATE
$a='THIS IS';
$b='MYSQLI PREPARED STATEMENT';
$c=30;
if($query->prepare("INSERT INTO sinhvien(ho,ten,tuoi)VALUES(?,?,?)")){
    $query->bind_param('ssi',$a,$b,$c);//BIND THE ? TO THES VARIABLES
    $query->execute();//NOW EXECUTE THEM
    echo "INSERTED INTO THE DATABASE WITH MYSQLI PREPARED STATEMENT";
}

?>
```